# How to check how many users are online?

Tags: iis, asp.net, maintenance

I administer a ASP.NET website that has decent traffic. In the middle of the day, I sometimes would need to either redeploy the website, change the configuration in the web.config file or make some update to the SQL Server.

In theory, when I make these changes, I can redirect the user to a "Maintainence page" that indicates that updates are in progress. But sometimes, the fix usually takes only a few seconds.

How would I check how many users are using the website and apply the quick changes when no one is online? I do have access to the web server and the database server.

Answer (score 7):

You could monitor active connections in real-time using System Monitor (type `perfmon` in the Run dialog box). Add the **"Web Service"** counter to monitor active Web connections.

Here is a [list of performance counters for IIS 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0a6c9f07-a70c-4c3d-b93d-5dfef593c744.mspx?mfr=true) (Microsoft Technet).